# Standard forces on a bike frame

Tags: design, framebuilding, force

Let's say I was going to design a bike frame for a specific size of individual. I'd start with some basic frame geometries, then I assume I'd calculate the necessary member sizes, stiffnesses, etc. by calculating the force on each member in a number of standard load scenarios (i.e. maximum force applied during standing pedaling, force on seat tube when sitting, cornering at high speeds, braking, etc.) Given these forces, I'd be able to correctly size each tube/member.

**My question is: what are reasonable forces to be used in these load scenarios?** I assume there are some standard forces used by bicycle designers for different load cases, but thus far I haven't been able to find these loads.

(For context not relevant for this question but perhaps of interest to the casual reader, I'd like to use these forces and a generative design-based software tool (Autodesk Fusion360) to design a bike frame that is near optimal for someone of my size and desired riding style. Probably will eventually try to machine said frame from wood. I know this is not a mainstream material choice but has been used to pretty good effect [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd0vt5v37B0)).

Comment: It's all in *Bicycles and Tricycles* by Sharp. Hopefully someone will be able to provide useful cliff notes as an answer.

Comment: (To be clear, the problem is that when you're using an unconventional material and you don't want to either way overbuild it or do a bunch of iterative testing, the other option is you need to do the math to figure out the loads on individual frame members, which for the most part is also in Sharp unless maybe you're talking about a chunkier monocoque type frame as opposed to tube-to-tube-ish. My understanding is that figuring out rough input forces is a simpler version of the same kind of exercise AND varies with some of the dimensions of the frame members in question anyway.)

Comment: To clarify, the question I'm asking is how you would calculate the forces for an arbitrary material. Let's ignore the specific material properties for a minute: how would I determine the design forces if I were, say, building a steel bike frame with tubular members? I am mostly interested in what the various design loading scenarios are and how the forces are calculated for these scenarios. I'll deal with the peculiarities of the selected design material (anisotropic behavior, stress concentrations at joints, etc) in due course.

Comment: Gotcha. My math background is pretty low but the Sharp book is often cited as one of the more accessible complete sources of that information. I believe it's all in there in a form that's pretty directly applicable to the bikes of today unless again they're less tube-to-tube-ish. *Bicycling Science* by Wilson has some of the same with easier language, but is less "hard" and may ultimately be less useful. I understand that getting book titles thrown at you may not feel useful, but the other side of it is that it's an area where a lot of the other knowledge out there is proprietary. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the proprietary nature of the problem seems to definitely restrict the amount of material available on the subject. Seems a bit bizarre that the most useful resource would be a 130 year old book but maybe they really said it all..

Comment: What you are asking for is a secret sauce of the bike industry. The forces in ordinary situations you describe are pretty easy to calculate, but to make a worthwhile dependable frame, it needs to be overbuilt, but not so overbuilt it's too heavy. That trade-off balancing act isn't simple. In any case, I think what might be best would be to design a bike frame from metal as though you were a custom framebuilder, using common tubing sizes, which has a bit of those practical trade-offs built into the tubing selection, then redesign the bike in wood, selecting tube profiles

Comment: that reasonably simulate the strength and stiffness performance of that metal bike. If you want to improve on that, you'll have to try again and again and iterate.

Comment: You know how much you weigh.  Figure it out!  (Note, though, that you do need to take into account "dynamic" forces from, eg, hitting a bump.  But these can be calculated by knowing acceleration, etc -- stuff that you need to have a general understanding of in any event.)

Comment: I understand the necessaries for static and mechanical analysis. I am looking some general guidance on: 1.) what load cases I should consider (I listed some above but if I go based on my intuition I may miss an important load case) and 2.) what kind of factors might be a good starting point for load magnification? I.e. Obviously the force applied to the pedal can be more than the weight of the rider, but is there a good rule of thumb for by how much?

Comment: @Derek G Just do some case analysis. For a road bike, this may include: dropping off a curb, hitting a pothole, sprinting, riding gravel, and perhaps a crash (keep the wall thicknesses reasonably high). I think there’s some kind of standard for bike frame strength too. Cat 1 is road only, cat 2 gravel, cat 3 XC/light trail, cat 4 aggressive trail, and cat 5 DH/freeride. There may be more data there if you can find it.

Comment: Another good book is bicycling science, by Wilson. I think it has sufficient detail though its scope is broad and there's a limit to how much they can squeeze in on a given topic

Comment: Wood could be good, but the joints (and joints to metal parts) will be the hard bits

Comment: @ChrisH - The Wright Brothers (who invented the powered airplane) built wood bikes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I've seen more recent examples too.  It's really an excellent material in many ways, but the skill required to make an optimised structure is in the craftsmanship as well as the engineering.  Bamboo bikes often cheat by using metal joint pieces

Comment: Don't forget that bike forces vary by type of bike.  A downhill bike has different forces on it than a road bike.

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is engineering. Even if you can calculate the correct thickness for all "reasonable" impacts and forces thrown at a bicycle, you still need to take into account that the bicycle will be used, so the material will undergo **hysteresis**.

A frame can stand a single impact providing a force of X, but it may fail after one hundred impacts of smaller force X/1000 (yes, you are reading correct, standing a *single* impact of force **X**, but failing after a *cumulative* impact force of **1/10** of **X**).
If you then bring into the picture a material that evolves with time, like wood, you should expect ... a lot of trial and error.

An example: you draw your ideal wood bike, knowing the tensile strength and other parameters of wood you calculate that the top tube should be long 30cm, have a diameter 1.8 cm and a thickness of 2 mm. However, with the use you realize that such a tube will produce some resonance and some vibration, so for some unlucky reasons hysteresis will cause the connection of the seat stays (calculated to be long 22 cm, diameter 1.2 cm, thickness 1.9 mm) to fail on average after 500 km.
You try to reinforce the connection, but the solution maybe is just to have a top tube with a larger diameter, or shorter, to dampen the vibrations/resonance.

How to proceed? you have two choices:

[scientific/industrial approach]

- the mechanical engineer way, such as this page hosted on sheldonbrown site
  https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/fea.htm or you check the latest peer reviewed research: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1687814017739513

[empirical approach]

- you take some frame building courses, where you get the experience of learning by doing, so you have a "feeling" for what is the right thickness/shape/angles etcetc.

It is not that the calculation of forces is complex or there are industrial secret preventing us from its understanding (well, there are industrial secrets on why a certain thing is built a certain way, but physics is not an industrial secret :D ).
The fact is that we have a very rough understanding of reality and forces at the microscopic scale, but we can obtain insight on the resulting macroscopic behavior of materials only via:

- engineering/advanced calculus/tests and experiments (use Finite Element software to calculate stresses and plastic behavior of the material and then you obtain the composite tube shapes of a Kestrel road bike https://www.compositesworld.com/articles/ultralight-carbon-fiberepoxy-road-bike-from-kestrel )

> Kestrel co-owner Preston Sandusky credits the low weight to the bike's
> "modular monocoque" frame, fabricated from three individually
> bladder-molded parts: the triangular front frame, and two two-pronged,
> U-shaped forks, which form the seat stay section (running from the top
> of the seat tube to the rear wheel dropouts) and chain stay section
> (from the bottom of the seat tube to the rear dropouts). Developed by
> former aerospace engineers at Kestrel's headquarters in Santa Cruz,
> Calif., U.S.A., using Pro-ENGINEER and RHINO 3-D Solid Modeling
> software (PTC, Needham, Mass., U.S.A.), the frame structures are
> fabricated

- via empirical reasoning (Columbus steel tubes works great to build a bicycle with drops, why? because it does! )

I would **NOT** be surprised if, after doing some calculation based on very simple principle, you would find out that a steel frame with thickness 0.1mm and a weight of 500 grams would be able to stand all the *forces* related to a standard cycling scenarios.

Comment: But then, how can anyone correctly calculate sufficient dimensions for objects in civil engineering, aerospace engineering, automotive etc. etc.? Isn’t the first step always to get a set of forces and then design an appropriate structure?

Comment: @Michael Have you noticed how in the last 30 years all the bridges are the same, all the airplanes look similar (check the various iterations of B737 wrt the Comac C919 wrt the Airbus A321 ... they are wildly less different than the first passenger jet airplanes)?
So there are two aspects to consider:
- a lot of engineering is based on empirical formula ... which are true because they stand the test of time;
- safety factors: a steel frame of 500gr would support you, but steel frame are generally around 2kg to last many more hysteresis cycles... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering

Comment: @EarlGray: But you can model/specify load cycles as well. Afaik revolutions in airplane design haven’t happened because they are too expensive (maybe because of safety), it’s easier, cheaper and safer to iterate on the same design.

Comment: You can model/specify forces and load cycles on untested material or untested structures, but they will be representative only if you already have data, and data come form intensive testing and ... usage!  
It's easier, cheaper and safer to consider hysteresis and to calculate forces acting on the same design, using the same material.
What you call "design" is simply equal to "to consider hysteresis and to calculate forces acting on the same structure, using the same material".

Comment: But OP is asking for forces, load cycles etc. I guess one could build a “traditional” diamond frame, attach a lot of strain gauges and measure real world data, but certainly someone has done that already?

Comment: @Michael done, but not for wood. 
Plus, most of the process at the crystal/fiber level are non-linear, cannot be interpolated (and absolutely not extrapolated) so even testing a certain frame with a certain tube thickness and another identical with 2x thickness (and therefore 2x the weight), does not guarantee that you can fill the dots in between...
In general we want to know how to build something safely, then we apply a safety factor to be on the very safe side ... and sometimes we can relax a bit the safety factors because we have decades of data (the case of aluminum frame in planes).

Comment: But when you have real world forces and load cycles, why would you be unable to design a suitable&safe frame? Isn’t the whole field of mechanical engineering based on the abstraction/assumption that materials are homogeneous and can be described with some simple numbers and tables? You are basically saying that mechanical engineering doesn’t work and is a fluke.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118708/discussion-between-earlgrey-and-michael).

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing some of the recommended sources above and giving the matter some thought myself, I came up with the following load cases for a hardtail mountain bike. These are by no means definitive but should cover the vast majority of normal use cases. I'll apply a factor of safety (probably 2.0) on top of the resulting calculations:

**Normal Use Load Cases:**

- Full effort standing start - assume 150% rider weight applied to one pedal, 25% rider weight upwards force applied to other pedal, and remainder of upwards force applied at handlebars
- Steady state pedaling - assume rider weight distributed between pedals and seat, applying say 400 watts of power.
- Climbing force - same as standing effort but with a 20% incline
- Cornering force - assume 1G (2 x rider weight) applied to pedals
- Front braking force - not exactly sure what I'll use here
- Rear braking force - apply maximum force before skid to rear disc caliper mounts based on a reasonable coefficient of friction for the tire and standard weight distribution
- Jump landing force - assume a 3-foot vertical drop onto both wheels, with 80% of rider weight on pedals. (Assume rigid fork) Bike and rider decelerate in a distance equal to tire distance from rim.
- Maximum seat force - 3 x rider weight applied to seat tube, roughly simulates going off a drop and landing on the seat

**Frame resilience tests:**

- Frontal impact on fork - apply a 200 pound force at the front dropouts in the direction of the back of the bike
- Bottom Bracket Pull Test - essentially hang a 750 lb weight from the bottom bracket
- Rear Stay Stiffness Test - apply a 30 lb force along the axis of the rear axle to one rear stay
- Torsional Test - apply 100% rider weight to one pedal to create a moment while fixing the head tube (to simulate frame torsion between pedal and handlebars)

Comment: Here’s some info on braking forces: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72863/what-are-the-typical-range-of-maximum-braking-friction-forces?r=SearchResults

Comment: Nice!
Regarding the comment from someone mentioning this is "secret sauce of the bike industry": beware of some big bicycle companies, they sued someone for something much more frivolous 
https://www.velonews.com/gear/specializeds-disastrous-trademark-case-is-unnecessary-to-defend-the-brand/ (I am joking ... I hope! )